How to invert a matrix with variables inside in pyomo problem?
In the model, I need to recalculate the inverse of (I-A) where I is identity matrix of rank n and A is a n*n matrix. I intend to change values of some elements in A matrix. One constraint is:
model.stock[(p,t)] == sum([model.L[(p,s,t)]*model.tec_s[(s,t)] for s in model.services])

And variable L is constrained as follows:
def cons(model,i,j,t,p,s):
return model.L[(p,s,t)] == L_matrix_df(A_var(A[t],i,j,t,po.value(model.var_share[(i,j,t)])).loc[p,s]
model.cons = po.Constraint(['c-Si PV','Wind'],['Electricity'],model.time, model.product, model.product, rule = cons)

The L_matrix_df function derives the inverse of (I-A) matrix and A_var function change the value as follows
A[t].loc[i,j]  = po.value(var_share[(i,j,t)]).
However, it find an optimal solution only when there is only on i item e.g 'c-Si PV' in constraint model.cons but when I add another element such as 'Wind' then it becomes infeasible. I do know how to use the po.value() since it seems to fix a value to the variable and do not allow to change it after a first guess. Without the po.value() the matrix cannot be inverted.
Anyone knows how to force the variable to take a value, do the inversion and then change it again until finding the optimum value?

your problem seems to be ill posed. Could you write your entire model in mathematical terms ?

Instead of using an explicit matrix inverse $x=inv(A)*b$, you can state this as a set of quadratic constraints: $Ax=b$ (quadratic as $A$ contains variables in your case). I.e. let the NLP solver handle the inversion.  Sometimes, this works with a local solver, but if the problem is not too large, a global solver may be better.
